# Laravel: 1055 'column' isn't in GROUP BY - Only with MariaDB

Tags: mysql, laravel, group-by, mariadb

I have a somewhat unusual problem and I've not been able to fully solve it.

I have the following statement, which on our local development branch (using MySQL) is working correctly and showing the info that's intended.

```
$productos = Producto::select(
            [
                'productos.*', 
                \DB::raw('COUNT(lotes.stock_actual) as stock_actual'), 
                \DB::raw('COUNT(stock_lote_reserva.cantidad) as reserva_actual'), 
                \DB::raw('COUNT(lotes.stock_actual)+COUNT(stock_lote_reserva.cantidad) as cantidad_fisica_total')
            ]
        )->leftJoin('lotes', function ($join) use ($ambiente_sucursal) {
            if($ambiente_sucursal)
            {
                $join->on('lotes.producto_id', '=', 'productos.id')
                    ->where('lotes.fecha_vencimiento', '>', \DB::raw('NOW()'))
                    ->whereIn('lotes.sucursal_id', $ambiente_sucursal);
            }
            else
            {
                $join->on('lotes.producto_id', '=', 'productos.id')
                    ->where('lotes.fecha_vencimiento', '>', \DB::raw('NOW()'));
            }
        })->leftJoin('stock_lote_reserva', function ($join) use ($ambiente_sucursal) {
                $join->on('stock_lote_reserva.lote_id', '=', 'lotes.id');
        })->groupBy('productos.id')
        ->orderBy('cantidad_fisica_total', 'DESC')
        ->with('tienda')->get();
```

However, when uploading it to the production server (MariaDB) we were greeted with an error that we've been unable to solve.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'amplifica_dev.productos.name' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `productos`.*, COUNT(lotes.stock_actual) as stock_actual, COUNT(stock_lote_reserva.cantidad) as reserva_actual, COUNT(lotes.stock_actual)+COUNT(stock_lote_reserva.cantidad) as cantidad_fisica_total from `productos` left join `lotes` on `lotes`.`producto_id` = `productos`.`id` and `lotes`.`fecha_vencimiento` > NOW() left join `stock_lote_reserva` on `stock_lote_reserva`.`lote_id` = `lotes`.`id` where `productos`.`deleted_at` is null group by `productos`.`id` order by `cantidad_fisica_total` desc)

When copying and pasting the query in the error into our DBA Tool (we were using DBeaver for this) the query completes successfully both in local and in the production server.

I've tried to enable the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY setting which is the only difference between local and remote databases, aside from being MySQL and MariaDB.

```
 \DB::statement("SET sql_mode=(SELECT CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'));");
```

However, this didn't have any effect.

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

SQL versions:
local `mysql  Ver 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))`
remote `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.31-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2`

Comment: Assuming that you have relationships set up for `lotes` and `stock_lote_reserva`, you could use [withCount](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#aggregating-related-models) instead.

Comment: MySQL is not MariaDB. They have a lot of code in common, but both have changed a lot since MariaDB forked in 2010. You should use the same product and version in development as you use in production, or you will encounter compatibility issues like this.

Comment: I would not only recommend to use the same database (MariaDB <> MySQL) in development, testing, and production, but to also use the exact same version of it. Since MariaDB is free of charge and free of licenses I don't see why the developers don't use it during normal development work. Nowadays you don't even need to to install it; a "docker run" will spin up a MariaDB in seconds.